# google app engine: getting form fields

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How do I get access to the form data. I want to do this before is_valid() is carried out. How do I access a field. I seem to be getting a blank address though.

The code looks like:

```
def post(self):
    data = CompanyForm(data=self.request.POST)
    map_url = ''    
    address = str(data['company_postcode'])

    address = address.replace(' ', '')
```

whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Request class documentation](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html), `Request` does not have a `POST` instance variable. You can call `self.request.get('company_postcode')` to obtain the posted value for `company_postcode`.

For debugging, the raw POST data can be obtained from `self.request.body`.

Comment: `google.appengine.ext.webapp.Request` is a `webob.Request` subclass; while the stuff inherited from webob isn't documented on the linked page, it's all there.